# Using a double border for a html table while having single solid border around cells

Tags: html, css

How can I make a table with a double border around the table, but single solid border around the cells?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px double black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

tr {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<h2>1.1 Subheading</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is my content for box 1</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
    <td>Here is my wonderful html table with long content that I have no idea how it will look until I see it</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>twinkle twinkle</td>
    <td>little star</td>
    <td>Yao Ming</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

The cells get overridden with a single border all the way around (rightly so). I could add 2 classes, `.row_start` and `.row_end`, and specifically call out borders for them so they'll have double on the end side, then single on the other three (likewise do this for the top cells and bottom cells). But I was wondering if there's a better way to do this all together.

Using only vanilla HTML/CSS, I'm writing a Word document with a bunch of tables. I've had no success with the Word object model so decided to create it using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have double borders, You can try this,

**HTML**

```
<table class="borders">....</table>
```

**CSS**

```
 .borders {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
  .borders:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by wrapping the `table` in a `div` element and setting border to the `div` element. You must make it display: inline-block and width: auto so it doesn't take full width and float just around the table.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px double black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

tr {
  padding: 0;
}

.table-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<h2>1.1 Subheading</h2>
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is my content for box 1</td>
      <td>Some other content</td>
      <td>Here is my wonderful html table with long content that I have no idea how it will look until I see it</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>twinkle twinkle</td>
      <td>little star</td>
      <td>Yao Ming</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider outline:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px double black;
  outline:2px solid red;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

tr {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<h2>1.1 Subheading</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is my content for box 1</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
    <td>Here is my wonderful html table with long content that I have no idea how it will look until I see it</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>twinkle twinkle</td>
    <td>little star</td>
    <td>Yao Ming</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Or `box-shadow`:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px double black;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px red;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

tr {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<h2>1.1 Subheading</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is my content for box 1</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
    <td>Here is my wonderful html table with long content that I have no idea how it will look until I see it</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>twinkle twinkle</td>
    <td>little star</td>
    <td>Yao Ming</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

And also consider `outline-offset` to create a distance between both border

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px double black;
  outline:2px solid red;
  outline-offset:2px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

tr {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<h2>1.1 Subheading</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is my content for box 1</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
    <td>Here is my wonderful html table with long content that I have no idea how it will look until I see it</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>twinkle twinkle</td>
    <td>little star</td>
    <td>Yao Ming</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```